# How can I increase size of my modal in table

Tags: html, css, html-table, modal-dialog

I made a table and I want to make the different cells clickable and that a modal appears. I have got that working when the modal is in one row, see test3 in snippet.

However, when I make a modal across multiple rows, it doesn't make the whole cell clickable, only a part of it. When I hover above it, it only changes the color of the clickable part, but I want the whole cell to be clickable and thus change color when I hover over it. Just like "test3".

How can I change this to make it span over the whole cell?

[image]

```js
var btn = document.querySelectorAll("button.modal-button");


var modals = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  btn[i].onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    modal = document.querySelector(e.target.getAttribute("href"));
    modal.style.display = "block";
  }
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
  spans[i].onclick = function() {
    for (var index in modals) {
      if (typeof modals[index].style !== 'undefined') modals[index].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target.classList.contains('modal')) {
    for (var index in modals) {
      if (typeof modals[index].style !== 'undefined') modals[index].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#tableone {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

#tableone td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  padding: 8px;
}

#tableone th {
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  background-color: rgba(0, 110, 167, 1);
  color: white;
}

.modalTD {
  padding: 0!important;
  background-color: #00a6d6;
}


/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 10px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: black;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.notebook {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 70%;
}

.notebook td.modalTD:hover .block:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: black;
}

.notebook td,
.notebook th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 0px;
}

.block {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
  background-color: #00a6d6;
  padding: 14px 28px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="centerjustify">
  <h2>Table 1</h2>
  <br>
  <table id="tableone" class="notebook">
    <tr id="category">
      <th style="background-color:transparent; color:black;"></th>
      <th style="background-color:transparent; color:black;" colspan=2>One</th>
      <th style="background-color:transparent; color:black;" colspan=2>Two</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="month">April</td>
      <td rowspan=4 class="modalTD">
        <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
        <button class="block modal-button" href="#myModal1">Test</button>

        <!-- The Modal -->
        <div id="myModal1" class="modal">

          <!-- Modal content -->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
              <p>Some other text...</p>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </td>
      <td rowspan=3 class="modalTD">
        <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
        <button class="block modal-button" href="#myModal2">Test2</button>

        <!-- The Modal -->
        <div id="myModal2" class="modal">

          <!-- Modal content -->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
              <p>Some other text...</p>
            </div>

          </div>

        </div>
      </td>
      <td colspan=2></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="month">May</td>


      <td colspan=2></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="month">June</td>
      <td colspan=2></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="month">July</td>


      <td></td>
      <td colspan=2 class="modalTD">
        <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
        <button class="block modal-button" href="#myModal3">Test 3</button>

        <!-- The Modal -->
        <div id="myModal3" class="modal">

          <!-- Modal content -->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
              <p>Some other text...</p>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </table>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the way what I've found to achieve that is to set the buttons height the same as outer td cells.

Here you have working example:

```js
var btn = document.querySelectorAll("button.modal-button");
var modalTD = document.querySelectorAll(".modalTD") // get modalTD


var modals = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  btn[i].style.height = modalTD[i].clientHeight + 'px' //set height of outer td to buttons
  btn[i].onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();    
    modal = document.querySelector(e.target.getAttribute("href"));
    modal.style.display = "block";
  }
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
  spans[i].onclick = function() {
    for (var index in modals) {
      if (typeof modals[index].style !== 'undefined') modals[index].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target.classList.contains('modal')) {
    for (var index in modals) {
      if (typeof modals[index].style !== 'undefined') modals[index].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#tableone {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

#tableone td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  padding: 8px;
}

#tableone th {
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  background-color: rgba(0, 110, 167, 1);
  color: white;
}

.modalTD {
  padding: 0!important;
  background-color: #00a6d6;
}


/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 10px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: black;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.notebook {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 70%;
}

.notebook td.modalTD:hover .block:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: black;
}

.notebook td,
.notebook th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 0px;
}

.block {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
  background-color: #00a6d6;
  padding: 14px 28px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="centerjustify">
  <h2>Table 1</h2>
  <br>
  <table id="tableone" class="notebook">
    <tr id="category">
      <th style="background-color:transparent; color:black;"></th>
      <th style="background-color:transparent; color:black;" colspan=2>One</th>
      <th style="background-color:transparent; color:black;" colspan=2>Two</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="month">April</td>
      <td rowspan=4 class="modalTD">
        <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
        <button class="block modal-button" href="#myModal1">Test</button>

        <!-- The Modal -->
        <div id="myModal1" class="modal">

          <!-- Modal content -->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
              <p>Some other text...</p>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </td>
      <td rowspan=3 class="modalTD">
        <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
        <button class="block modal-button" href="#myModal2">Test2</button>

        <!-- The Modal -->
        <div id="myModal2" class="modal">

          <!-- Modal content -->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
              <p>Some other text...</p>
            </div>

          </div>

        </div>
      </td>
      <td colspan=2></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="month">May</td>


      <td colspan=2></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="month">June</td>
      <td colspan=2></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="month">July</td>


      <td></td>
      <td colspan=2 class="modalTD">
        <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
        <button class="block modal-button" href="#myModal3">Test 3</button>

        <!-- The Modal -->
        <div id="myModal3" class="modal">

          <!-- Modal content -->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
              <p>Some other text...</p>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </table>

</div>
```

The second approach is to make whole modalTD cell clickable and set hover style in stylesheet to it:

```js
var btn = document.querySelectorAll("button.modal-button");
var modalTD = document.querySelectorAll(".modalTD") // get modalTD


var modals = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  var num = i
  modalTD[i].onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();    
    modal = document.querySelector("#myModal" + num);
    modal.style.display = "block";
  }
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
  spans[i].onclick = function() {
    for (var index in modals) {
      if (typeof modals[index].style !== 'undefined') modals[index].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target.classList.contains('modal')) {
    for (var index in modals) {
      if (typeof modals[index].style !== 'undefined') modals[index].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#tableone {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

#tableone td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  padding: 8px;
}

#tableone th {
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  background-color: rgba(0, 110, 167, 1);
  color: white;
}

.modalTD {
  padding: 0!important;
  background-color: #00a6d6;
}

/* The ModalTD Hover */

.modalTD:hover{
  background-color: yellow;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modalTD:hover .modal-button{
  background-color: yellow;
}


/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 10px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: black;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.notebook {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 70%;
}

.notebook td.modalTD:hover .block:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: black;
}

.notebook td,
.notebook th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 0px;
}

.block {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
  background-color: #00a6d6;
  padding: 14px 28px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="centerjustify">
  <h2>Table 1</h2>
  <br>
  <table id="tableone" class="notebook">
    <tr id="category">
      <th style="background-color:transparent; color:black;"></th>
      <th style="background-color:transparent; color:black;" colspan=2>One</th>
      <th style="background-color:transparent; color:black;" colspan=2>Two</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="month">April</td>
      <td rowspan=4 class="modalTD">
        <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
        <button class="block modal-button" href="#myModal1">Test</button>

        <!-- The Modal -->
        <div id="myModal1" class="modal">

          <!-- Modal content -->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
              <p>Some other text...</p>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </td>
      <td rowspan=3 class="modalTD">
        <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
        <button class="block modal-button" href="#myModal2">Test2</button>

        <!-- The Modal -->
        <div id="myModal2" class="modal">

          <!-- Modal content -->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
              <p>Some other text...</p>
            </div>

          </div>

        </div>
      </td>
      <td colspan=2></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="month">May</td>


      <td colspan=2></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="month">June</td>
      <td colspan=2></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="month">July</td>


      <td></td>
      <td colspan=2 class="modalTD">
        <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
        <button class="block modal-button" href="#myModal3">Test 3</button>

        <!-- The Modal -->
        <div id="myModal3" class="modal">

          <!-- Modal content -->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
              <p>Some other text...</p>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: Great it works! thank you so much. However, I have one more question. It doesn't seem to work for cells that have a colspan. Do you perhaps know the answer for that as well?

Comment: If you want to achieve this effect for colspans, you should get and set width instead of height

Comment: @Weronika I suppose there were some performance issues, but I'm not sure why. I've updated my answear with a little workaround solution. Hope it'll helps.

Comment: This is amazing!! Thank you so much!! Only the newly updated script makes the close button (not shown here in my example) not functional. Do you perhaps know how to fix this as well?